# Entity Framework Core Insert list of one-to-one-or-zero (shared primary key association) foreign key conflict

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to do an insert of a list of objects. These objects are formed by 2 separate sub-objects, linked by 0 to 1 relation.

If I insert one object at a time, it works, but if I try to insert more than one, the call to `SaveChanges` throws a "foreign key" error. I know that 0-to-1 relations need to know the main relation object index. But, is there a way to fix this?

This is what I'm trying to do:

This code works:

```
ElementoVariante ElementoVariante1 = new()
{
    TipoElementoNome = EnumTipoElemento.ProdottoFinito,
    ElementoPadreId = 17491,
    SchedaSerieProdotto = new SchedaSerieProdotto()
    {
        S = s,
        P = p
    }
};
context.ElementoVariante.Add(ElementoVariante1);
context.SaveChanges();
```

This code however does not work:

```
ElementoVariante ElementoVariante1 = new()
{
    TipoElementoNome = EnumTipoElemento.ProdottoFinito,
    ElementoPadreId = 17491,
    SchedaSerieProdotto = new SchedaSerieProdotto()
    {
        S = s,
        P = p
    }
};
context.ElementoVariante.Add(ElementoVariante1);

ElementoVariante ElementoVariante2 = new()
{
    TipoElementoNome = EnumTipoElemento.ProdottoFinito,
    ElementoPadreId = 17491,
    SchedaSerieProdotto = new SchedaSerieProdotto()
    {
        S = s,
        P = p
    }
};
context.ElementoVariante.Add(ElementoVariante2);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Not really sure if I understood your question correctly since it seems your code is in (italian?). But I guess you have a 1:1 relation between two tables and link them over the field ElemtoPadreID (ParentID?). In a 1:1 relationship you can not use the same value twice. Try to switch the value of ElementoPadreId on the second object to a differenct value.

Comment: You are right, i did not explain this well.
ElementoPadre has a list of "ElementoVariante", so, the ElementoPadreId is ok to be de same.
SchedaSerieProdotto has 1:1 relation with ElementoVariante with ElementoVarianteId, that is not showed in code.

Comment: Can you try to modify the values of S and P and see if it works? Maybe your constraints are wrong in your schema

Comment: Just tried, assigned different values to S and P but same. i think i'll go for multiple SaveChanges, i'm tring to solve this from yesterday. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.
I think the problem is inside EF Core 5.
Table 'SchedaSerieProdotto' has a parent table 'SchedaBase', and i was doing this: "builder.Entity().ToTable("SchedaSerieProdotto")" to split tables.
I removed that, merged the 2 tables in one, adding Discriminator columns, and now it all works.
I think it's a TPT problem of EF Core 5, maybe they fixed it in latest releases, like EF Core 7